# How to attach 3 data frames horizontally and directly without using any joins?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: A data frame that contains only Country/Region column]

I have a data frame that contains only the Country/Region column

The second data frame that contains only the Confirmed column

[image]

And the third data frame contains only the Deaths column

[image]

The question is how to directly attach these three data frame above without using any complicated method ?

I want the result like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 `pd.merge`s.

(1) Merge the first two (`df1` and `df2`) on their indices

(2) Merge the dataframe from (1) with `df3` on `'Country/Region'`. Since the dataframe from (1) has `'Country/Region'` as a column and `df3` has it as index, you have to pass `left_on=True, right_index=True`:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(df3, left_on='Country/Region', right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```